# TCP/IP receiving ACK after retransmittion data

Tags: tcp, ip, layer4

Lets say we send segment A with some data. Sender waits for ACK from receiver but there is timeout and sender send this segment (A) again. After this, sender received delayed ACK segment (B). What is now happening with duplicated data/ack packets?

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

In short, nothing.  The connection resumes communicating.  There is no duplicate *data*, only a duplicate *segment*.  Each segment contains a sequence number that permits the receiver to discard duplicate data and re-order out of order segments so that the receiver sees the data stream as the correct sequence of bytes.